# How do I know which /dev/ttyS* is my serial port?

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have a laptop which has only one serial port.

I went into:

```
/dev
```

directory, and I found:

```
ttyS0
ttyS1
ttyS2
ttyS3
```

How do I know which of those "ttyS" refers to my serial port?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530096/how-to-find-all-serial-devices-ttys-ttyusb-on-linux-without-opening-them

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think it's this command:

```
dmesg | grep tty
```

Running that on my own Linux box (which only has 1 Serial port) produces a single ttyS0 output line. Try it on your own, you will see what I mean.

Comment: The only problem is that dmesg output can be cleared - so if you run this too late, you're out of luck. Looking at /proc/tty/driver/serial seems the more robust answer and then check for rx interrupts increasing in count as you write data to that port

Answer (score 22):

See which UARTs where detected in `/proc/tty/driver/serial`. A line with `uart:unknown` means: nothing detected (and likely not existent).

```
# cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A port:000003F8 irq:4 tx:0 rx:0
1: uart:16550A port:000002F8 irq:3 tx:111780 rx:1321 RTS|DTR|DSR
2: uart:unknown port:000003E8 irq:4
3: uart:unknown port:000002E8 irq:3
```

If you see any of the CTS, DSR, (D)CD or RI flags (these are input signals), like on UART no. 1 above, you can even be pretty sure that there actually is something connected and driving these lines. Same is true for the rx-byte-count.

Seeing a positive tx-byte-count, RTS and/or DTR only reveals that some software accessed the device and ordered it to set those signals or send bytes here, but not if something was listening.

Note: you might see more ports available in hardware than ports reaching the outside of your computer in form of a connector.

Answer (score 10):

If you need to do this programmatically reading the output from dmesg can be troublesome, instead the folder /dev/serial/by-id has sym links that are named after identifiable data of your device and point to the specific /dev/tty* they are connected to.

I'm not sure if this is some special udev rule that is distribution specific, but it works well in Ubuntu, let me know if it works.

Comment: For the record, /dev/serial does not appear by default in Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) (no idea about previous versions)

Answer (score 8):

`ttyS0` through `3` correspond to `COM1` through `4`, respectively. They usually have the same hardware resources and are not always detectable, so they always exist.

Comment: thanks for the answer. So say I want to tell Linux that I want ttyS0 to map to my serial port hardware, what do I need to do?

Comment: You would use `setserial` to map the resources ttyS0 uses to that of your serial port. http://linux.die.net/man/8/setserial  This isn't normally required though, since anything beyond COM4 usually has enough auxiliary hardware to allow Linux to detect it and add a serial device as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the command `setserial` which uses `/proc/tty/driver/serial` to get it's data.

```
# setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123]
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
```

Comment: setserial -a /dev/tty0
Cannot get serial info: Inappropriate ioctl for device