# Why I have /dev/ttyS* on Linux when my laptop have no serial/RS232/COM1 port?

Tags: linux, debian, serial-port

I am running Debian Wheezy and my laptop does not have serial port. Why do I have `/dev/ttyS*`, and what will happen when I try to read/write to them?

My config:

```
└──> ll /dev/ttyS*
crw-rw---T 1 root dialout 4, 64 Apr 30 09:21 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---T 1 root dialout 4, 65 Apr 30 09:21 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw---T 1 root dialout 4, 66 Apr 30 09:21 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw---T 1 root dialout 4, 67 Apr 30 09:21 /dev/ttyS3

└──> sudo cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A port:000003F8 irq:4 tx:0 rx:0
1: uart:unknown port:000002F8 irq:3
2: uart:unknown port:000003E8 irq:4
3: uart:unknown port:000002E8 irq:3

└──> stty -g
6d02:5:4bf:8a3b:3:1c:7f:15:4:0:1:ff:11:13:1a:ff:12:f:17:16:ff:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0

└──> dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.653544] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    0.712718] 00:02: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
```

PS: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/131044/how-do-i-know-which-dev-ttys-is-my-serial-port) is mentioned case when user has one port and under /dev he has 4 but I have none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very probable that the ttyS0 port actually exists on your motherboard. And very possibly there is also a connector on the motherboard to use it too! When I bought my last board, I came to that conclusion too (by seeing the port listed), I then looked up all connectors in the board's manual. There was no direct connector to the outside, just a small 'header'. So I ran a cable to a db9 outside connector, and all is working!

The following three (`ttyS1-S3`) most probably do NOT exist, but are listed because the serial port driver tested them, which is the default action in many Linuxes. See the manual page for `setserial`, which is the function called when Linux is booted up. It says:

> During the normal bootup process, only COM ports 1-4 are initialized,
>   using the  default I/O ports and IRQ values, as listed below

EDIT: By the way, it's easy to see if the `ttyS*` work as files or not. Just try to send something to them by console command:

```
cat <some_short_file> > /dev/ttyS1
```

will probably give an `I/O error`, because there is no driver connected. The same for `ttyS0` will work normally. The `>` in the command redirects the output of the `cat` command to the serial port. `cp shortfile /dev/ttyS0` works too.

EDIT: ttyS1-S3 are not physically there, so no, you can't use them. There are other devices you can use as virtual ports, such as pseudoterminals (pty) and loop devices. Check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) and the [man pages for ptys](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pty). Where ptys are character devices, you can use loop devices for block transfer (eg. for virtual disks). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) and [man page documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/8/losetup).

Answer (score 4):

These ports actually exist on your motherboard. They are just not connected to an external port like they are in (some) desktops.

Comment: Can i use them somehow? I mean some virtual forwarding etc not physical wiring.

Comment: As long as they're not connected to anything, they're useless. But you can try…

Comment: How? I have seen some socat com1 forwarding for example

Comment: Download and install minicom: `sudo apt-get install minicom` and then just launch it: `minicom`. Press Ctrl + A, select serial port setup, and to the serial port window write ttyS0 or what you want.